# foreach in Perl and Tcl

Tags: perl, tcl

I have a Perl script which iterates an array like below:

```
my @GPO_regs = qw(0x70034 0x70038 0x7003C 0x70040 0x70044);

foreach my $register (@GPO_regs) { write_register($register, 0x0000) };
```

What should be the tcl equivalent of above? Is this correct?

```
set GPO_regs "0x70034 0x70038 0x7003C 0x70040 0x70044"

foreach {regs} [array get GPO_regs] { write_register $regs 0x0000}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GPO_regs here is a list, not an array, so all you need to interate over it is

```
foreach regs $GPO_regs {write_register $regs 0x0000}
```

Comment: In the function write_register,  I simply want to print the register value and 0x0000, but the function call is not working:      proc write_register {$regs $value} {
     puts [format "Value to be written at %s register is %s" $register $value]
}

Comment: To get the parameters passed correctly, the definition of write_register should be
`proc write_register {register value} { puts [format "Value to be written at %s register is %s" $register $value] }`